# How to display in the browser a page rendered by a view spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In a Rails 4.2 app I have a view spec that is behaving unexpectedly. The spec fails, whereas checking the view in the browser from the development environment would suggest the spec should pass.

In a feature spec I can call capybara's `save_and_open_page` to inspect a view rendered by a spec in the browser, to help with debugging.

How can I do the same in a view spec? `save_and_open_page` does not work in view specs.

```
undefined local variable or method `save_and_open_page'
```

## EDIT

I have tried saving and opening a file directly by including the following in the spec

```
...
render
File.open('/tmp/test.html','w'){|file| file.write(contents)};
...
```

with the following options

```
contents = response.body
contents = response
contents = rendered
```

All of which generate an empty/ blank page. Is this the right track? And if so, what should I be writing to `file`?

## EDIT

The spec is as follows:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "countries/show.html.erb", focus: true do

  it 'displays country correctly' do

    @country = assign(:country, stub_model(Country,
      name: "Country A",
      alpha: "AA",
      latitude: 1.248392,
      longitude: -20.47389
    ))

    render

    # NOT WORKING - displays empty page
    # File.open('/tmp/test.html','w'){|file| file.write(rendered)}; `open '/tmp/test.html'`

    expect(rendered).to have_selector("h1", text: 'Country A')

  end

end
```

Comment: The only part of capybara really useful in view specs is the Rspec matchers. To view the html in a browser you should be able to save the contents of `rendered` to a file and then manually open it in a browser.  You potentially won't have CSS or JS files accessible though.  You might also want to post your failure, people may have ideas of why it's failing.

Comment: *In a feature spec I can call capybara's save_and_open_page*. Maybe use feature specs instead of view specs?

Comment: thanks @TomWalpole. I had tried calling `render  File.open('/tmp/test.html','w'){|file| file.write(response.body)}; `open '/tmp/test.html'` in the spec, but this is rendering a blank page. Is `response.body` correct? I a having trouble tracking down documentation on this.

Comment: @zetetic a comparable feature spec is passing, which makes it more odd that this view spec is failing. I'd like to get to the bottom of this to confirm whether this is a bug in the spec, or whether the spec is indeed highlighting an error in the code. Also, this is a mature app so would like to align with existing conventions

Comment: @AndyHarvey a controller spec would have response, a view spec has `rendered`  https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/view-specs/view-spec

Comment: thanks @TomWalpole, I had tried `rendered` as well. I've added some details to the question. Grateful for any other thoughts/ ideas you may have.

Comment: Maybe add the rest of your test too

Comment: @TomWalpole I have added the spec. I appreciate all your help, thanks!!

Comment: It all looks correct and `rendered` should return a string with the rendered template contents, so either we're missing something basic or your countries/show.html.erb template isn't actually rendering anything.  Have you looked in the /tmp/test.html to see if it has any contents or are you only looking at what appears in your browser?  I guess the last thing to do would be to add your countries/show.html.erb template to the question

Comment: OK, I think I've figured this out. All the content in the show template is in `content_for` blocks, that are then yielding into several 'containers/modules' in the layout template. As the layout is not rendered by this spec, so test.html is empty. Is there a way to force the layout to be rendered? Or will this view have to be re-written to allow testing in this way?

Comment: If you explicitly specify the template you can specify a layout too    `render template: 'countries/show', layout: 'layouts/application'`

Comment: Or - you could access `view.content_for(:name_of_content_for_block)` to check the contents that have been rendered to a specific content_for